# How to update a domain service when the .edmx file is updated?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to update a Domain Service?

Right now I delete the service and add again its stupid.

Answer (score 1):

There's no update support in the UI, but if you're just returning whole entities there should be no reason to regenerate, everything should just flow through when you update the edmx and rebuild the project (to re-run codegen for the client).

Answer (score 1):

Just for information if anyone else stumbles upon this thread in desperation (like I just did) ...

I updated my edmx model in a Silverlight application, having only renamed one database column and added a couple of foreign keys, and the Client project immediately started generating 30+ fatal errors, all due to the fact that, despite the Web project building "successfully", it did *not* generate the app.g.vb "generated code file" for the client, resulting in "WebContext not defined", missing ApplicationResources etc etc.

The first time this happened I just gave up, deleted the edmx file and the domain service and started again.

The *second* time it happened I got angry, but this time I just deleted and re-created the domain service, and everything went back to normal.

So it looks like there are definitely some modifications you *can't* make to the edmx model without requiring re-creation of the Domain Service.

Ade.